# C# Case statment string or string

Tags: c#, switch-statement

```
switch (newButton.fileExtension)
            {
                case ".txt":
                    newButton.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"Some Directory\Project Code\Project images\Text document.png");
                    break;
                case (".png") || (".jpg") || (".gif"):
                    newButton.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"Some Directory\Project images\Picture document.png");
                    break;
                case ".doc":
                    newButton.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"Some Directory\Project Code\Project images\Word Document.png");
                    break;
                default:
                    newButton.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"Some Directory\Project Code\Project images\Unknown Document.png");
                    break;

            }
```

I would like to use a switch statement to check what newButton file type is, however c# doesn't allow you to do "string" || "string" is there a work around to this or should I just use If Else statements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

one possiblitiy which should work should be

```
switch (newButton.fileExtension)
        {
            case ".txt":
                newButton.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"Some Directory\Project Code\Project images\Text document.png");
                break;
            case ".png":
            case ".jpg":
            case ".gif":
                newButton.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"Some Directory\Project images\Picture document.png");
                break;
            case ".doc":
                newButton.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"Some Directory\Project Code\Project images\Word Document.png");
                break;
            default:
                newButton.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"Some Directory\Project Code\Project images\Unknown Document.png");
                break;

        }
```

Answer (score 5):

Just use multiple `case` statements without `break` between them:

```
case ".png":
case ".jpg":
case ".gif":
    newButton.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"Some Directory\Project images\Picture document.png");
    break;
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers will help you achieve what you want to do but I would like to point another direction you can take.

I am pretty sure these buttons when clicked do different things since they represent different document types. You probably have code related to that document type in the click handler and then the handler may call some other methods wherein you need to execute different parts of the code based on the document type.

I would create 5 classes: TextDocument, PictureDocument, WordDocument, DefaultDocument and BaseDocument. In the BaseDocument you can put an abstract property named ImagePath and a non abstract DocumentImage property and an abstract method named whatever is appropriate for the code to execute when the button is clicked. The inheriting classes will provide the path and set the ImagePath property. When the ImagePath property is set, you can create the Image object and set the DocumentImage property.

Look for other common code and keep pushing it to the BaseDocument class. At then end you will have less duplicate code and you will have the code for each document type nicely separated. You will also have a cleaner design. I do not have time right now but if you need help with the code for this approach, let me know and I can help you with that.

Comment: Good idea however I was using the same methods regardless of file types. This project was a cloud storage app so the methods were download, upload, delete ect. These methods are independent of file type. The only difference was graphical image icon. Thanks for the suggestion though ill bare it in mind for future projects.